# Better Autocompletion in SublimeText2?

Tags: html, sublimetext2

Basically I was learning HTML/CSS via this tutorial:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1Vqr1MdRmg&feature=player_detailpage#t=170s

Now at the linked time, notice how the narrator (who is using SublimeText2 on a Mac) gets a popup for autocompletion of the value of the attribute text-decoration="". 
I'm using ST2 on Windows 64 bit, but I don't get any such popup. I've been through the settings file of ST2 as well, but didn't find any option to enable such a thing?

How do I get ST2 to autocomplete attributes and their values? Currently it does so only with tags.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: As Thomas Allen said below, your using the wrong syntax for the CSS attribute text-decoration. The tutorial you are following is using what is called inline CSS, whereas it adds styling via the style attribute on HTML elements. This is probably what led to your confusion. Word of the wise you should consider locating another tutorial that uses external CSS, where you strictly use HTML in your .html files and you link to an external .css file for your styling. This is best practice and will help you get familiar with each language syntax easier.

Comment: Also ST2 does offer HTML autocompletion by default, but you can look into [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/Kronuz/SublimeCodeIntel) for improved functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
text-decoration:blahblah;
```

That's right CSS syntax.
Try it!